# swap character variables using pointers

Tags: c++

Ok. It might be a silly question.

I am trying to swap two character variables using pointers.following is my code.

```
void swap_char(char* x, char* y)
{ 
char *tmp=x;
 *x=*y;
*y=*tmp;  

/* int t=*x;
 *x=*y;        // this works fine and i understand
*y=t;
*/

}
```

and function call is--

```
swap_char(&s[0],&s[j]); // where s is std::string variable
```

value pointed by both x and y is same as value pointed by y after swapping..

What i am i doing wrong here

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to use pointers? Anyway, you need a temporary variable into which you can store one of the two values you want to swap. Since your code only involves pointers, you don't have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmp` and `x` point to the same location after `char* tmp=x`, so when you write

```
*x = *y;
```

`*tmp` is also changed. Meaning the subsequent

```
*y = *tmp;
```

is a no-op.

Use `std::swap`.

Answer (score 3):

You should be storing the value that `x` points at in `tmp`, not the address `x` itself (which means that `tmp` should be a `char`).

Since you have `tmp` set to `x`, your code is essentially equivalent to:

```
*x = *y;
*y = *x;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll base my change on your original code - so that you see your mistake. What you should have done was assign the "value" of x to tmp - and not the pointer itself. The latter is what happens with your tmp declaration/initialization. Details inline with code.

```
void swap_char(char* x, char* y)
{ 
//  char *tmp=x; // this would create a new tmp pointer and assign "tmp" with x - and NOT "*tmp" with *x".
    char tmp = *x; // new code - store the VALUE pointed by x in tmp
     *x=*y; // store VALUE pointed by y to storage pointed by x
    *y=tmp; // modified to delete * from tmp - store VALUE of tmp to storage pointed by y
}
```